# The proper way to set user ForeignKey value in DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the comment str."""
        return "'{}'".format(self.content)
```

And its serializer looks like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

So far so good when it comes to retrieve data, but when I want to `create` a new `Comment`, what would be the proper way to do so?

My view:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = []
        if self.action == 'create':
            permissions.append(IsAuthenticated)
        return [p() for p in permissions]

    def create(self, request):
        """Create a comment in some post."""

        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():  # False because user value is missing.
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)
```

That's ok, I tried by overriding `validate_user` and letting it just `pass`, but validation is still running when I call `is_valid`. Also I tried to append `request.user` to `serializer.data`, but it's immutable.
How could I achieve this if I need to use `request.user`? The value that I need to set to this field of the serializer is not in `request.data`. (I don't think letting the front end send the user id would be a good idea).

Another solution I have in mind is by making `user` ReadOnly in the `serializer`, and then adding it in the Django object when I call to `save()`. But I want to know what is the cleaner, restful way to do so with DRF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alter the serializer to use the context and patch the user field:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

In the `CommentViewSet`, you do not override `create`, since the `create` function is more complex, and will provide the context to the serializer:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return [IsAuthenticated()]
        return []

    # no create
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to set *user as `read_only` field*, which will turn off the validation.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

Then, override the **`perform_create(...)`** method of the viewset,

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = []
        if self.action == 'create':
            permissions.append(IsAuthenticated)
        return [p() for p in permissions]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**Note:**
You should remove the **`create(...)`** method of the ***viewset*** since it is doing nothing *"in your case"*

Answer (score 1):

models.py :

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the comment str."""
        return "'{}'".format(self.content)
   
    def get_username(self):
        return self.user.get_username()

    def get_post_title(self):
        return self.post.title
    
    # and so on ...
```

serializers.py :

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    post_title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
              "id", "username", "post_title", "content"
          ]
    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.get_username()

    def get_post_title(self, obj):
        return obj.get_post_title()
```

views.py :

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class CommentViewSet(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Comment
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```